# What are the differences between these four verbs: induce, entice, tempt and seduce?

Tags: differences

I'm confused! Can someone give me some sentences to explain the usage of these four verbs ("induce", "entice", "tempt", "seduce")?

> From Oxford Dictionary,
>
> "Induce": succeed in persuading or influencing (someone) to do something
>
> "entice": attract or tempt by offering pleasure or advantage
>
> "tempt": entice or attempt to entice (someone) to do or acquire something that they find attractive but know to be wrong or not beneficial
>
> "seduce": attract (someone) to a belief or into a course of action that is inadvisable or foolhardy

They seem to have the same meaning, i.e. attract someone to do something, so I am wondering what the exact differences are between them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Could you explain why you think these words are confusing? Have you looked them up in a dictionary? What is specifically confusing about them? To me they all seem different.

Comment: From Oxford Dictionary,

"Induce": succeed in persuading or influencing (someone) to do something
"entice": attract or tempt by offering pleasure or advantage
"tempt": entice or attempt to entice (someone) to do or acquire something that they find attractive but know to be wrong or not beneficial
"seduce": attract (someone) to a belief or into a course of action that is inadvisable or foolhardy

They seem like have the same meaning, i.e. attract someone to do something, so I am wondering what the exact differences are between them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are similar but some more than others:

- 'Tempted' and 'enticed' are very similar and are closest to your generic meaning of 'attract someone to do something'. They are both about the mental state; there's no guarantee that the subject took the bait. 'enticed' is a little rarer word. Also, 'enticed' has the feeling of attempting to act on the intent, where 'tempted' is more like 'really wants'.

> The man was **tempted** by the long odds on the race as his last chance for redemption
>
> The man was **enticed** by the short line at the bookie instead of the crowded OTC.

- 'induced' is much more general and clinical, meaning closer to 'caused', and the thing induced actually happened. No mental state or intention is involved.

> The man was **induced** to go to the racetrack by his gambling addiction.

- 'seduced' is usually used in a sexual context (or metaphorically) and the 'action' happened (a tryst or a change in mental state); 'strongly enamored'. (Literally it means 'to convince someone to have an affair'

> The man was **seduced** by the confidence of the hostess.

Answer (score 1):

- The cat was induced to vomit by a dose of ipecac.

  > Verb
  >   *induce* ‎(third-person singular simple present *induce*s, present participle
  >   *inducing*, simple past and past participle *induced*)
  >
  > 2. (transitive) **To cause, bring about, lead to**.
- The cat was enticed into the trap with fish.

  > Verb
  >   *entice* ‎(third-person singular simple present entices, present participle *enticing*, simple past and past participle *enticed*)
  >
  > 1. (transitive) **To lure; to attract by arousing desire or hope.**
- The cat was tempted by the goldfish in the bowl.

  > Verb
  >   *tempt* ‎(third-person singular simple present *tempts*, present participle *tempting*, simple past and past participle *tempted*)
  >
  > 2. (transitive) **To attract; to allure**.
- The cat was seduced into sitting on my lap by the potent catnip.

  > Verb
  >   *seduce* ‎(third-person singular simple present *seduces*, present participle *seducing*, simple past and past participle *seduced*)
  >
  > 4. **To win over or attract someone**.

All definitions courtesy of [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/).

Comment: Examples does not an explanation make.

Comment: Added some partial definitions for clarification.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I guess different people learn in different ways.  For me, examples are the best way to see what's going on!

Comment: @aparente001 Examples are good, but not always enough. You could replace 'entice' with 'tempted' in the second example and both would make sense, so more is needed than a single example to explain how they're different. That could be a definition, or a much broader range of examples that show how the words aren't equivalent.

Comment: @curiousdannii - The definitions do add value, definitely.